# Если мы вызываем функцию, то в стеке создаётся копия вызываемой функции?

Tags: c++, стек

Я сейчас изучаю указатели, и у меня возник вопрос - если мы вызываем функцию, то в стеке создаётся копия вызываемой функции или нет?

Comment: нет, при вызове функции происходит лишь обращение к этой функции - сама функция не копируется

Comment: В стеке создается *кадр стека* (stack frame) для нее, куда входят *в общем случае* точка возврата, локальные переменные, передаваемые аргументы, возвращаемое значение, но сам код функции не копируется - зачем?...

Comment: А для чего тогда нужны указатели на функции?

Comment: @NotAMaster Как минимум чтобы передавать одну функцию в другую функцию.

Comment: То есть это - основная задача указателей на функции?

Comment: @NotAMaster Уж не знаю, основная или нет, но одна из.